# select even/odd class element

Tags: html, css

I want a selector that selects the element that has elementWrapper as parent. If the parent element is even, make the child element float right, if its odd, make it float left.

The result should look something like this:

```
    <body>
        <style>
            .elementWrapper
            {
                width:100%;
                height:100px;
            }

            header, nav, div div, footer
            {
                width:50%;
                height:100px;
                background:#000;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="elementWrapper">
            <header style="float:left;"></header>
        </div>
        <div class="elementWrapper">
            <nav style="float:right;"></nav>
        </div>
        <div class="elementWrapper">
            <div style="float:left;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="elementWrapper">
            <footer style="float:right;"></footer>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Is this possible with css selectors or should I use js here?
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnDoe/4sBkZ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4sBkZ/2/)

```
.elementWrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
.elementWrapper:nth-child(even) * {
    float:left;
}
.elementWrapper:nth-child(odd) *{
   float:right;
}
```

If you have sub element than you should be specific

```
    .elementWrapper:nth-child(odd) > header,
    .elementWrapper:nth-child(odd) > nav,
    .elementWrapper:nth-child(odd) > footer,
    .elementWrapper:nth-child(odd) > div{
       float:right;
    }
```

Comment: i have tried your code, although the child element is floated the right way, all children of the floated element are also floated that way. It should only float the element beneath the elementWrapper class.

Comment: yes this is working for me. I was hoping for a more universal way of doing this, but it does the trick, thank you rajesh.

Answer (score 3):

Use `nth-child(odd)` || `nth-child(even)` for this.
 [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SzS5N/1/)

This **css** should do for you i think :

```
 .elementWrapper:nth-child(odd) {
       float:left;
    }
    .elementWrapper:nth-child(even) {
        float:right;
    }
```

Comment: we're getting close, but this makes my wrapper float left or right, and since I give my wrapper a width of 100% floating the wrapper in that way wont help here. its the element that has elementWrapper as a parent that should float left or right.